# Free Museum Sundays Florence

Tags: italy, fees-and-charges, museums, florence

Are Free Museum Sundays only valid for Italian residents? I live In germany and have a valid blue card permit. Can I still avail these sunday offers? If yes, do I need to book something prior or do I just go wait in the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are Free Museum Sundays only valid for Italian residents?

There are 2 different initiatives

- national museums (the whole of Italy)
- city museums of Florence

Based on the 2 pages I found, only the **city museums of Florence** restricts the free entry to the residents of the **province of Florence**.

[image]

Since you have not supplied a link that uses this term, I assume that it will be similar to the first link below which also list the museums seperatly (free for everyone and only free for residents of the province of Florence).

---

> [2023-08-28: Sunday at the Museum in Florence](https://www.firenzemadeintuscany.com/en/article/sunday-at-the-museum-in-florence-and-tuscany/)
> As on every first Sunday of the month, the free museums in Florence are back **for everyone**, thanks to the **Domenica al museo** initiative, **while residents** - thanks to the La **Domenica Metropolitana** initiative - in the Metropolitan City of Florence can visit the civic museums run by the city council free of charge, where guided tours and family visits are also planned.

- **Domenica al museo** initiative

  - for everyone

  > [Free Museums Florence 2023 > First Sunday of the month and beyond](https://www.imuseidifirenze.it/musei-gratis-firenze/)
  > With the Ministerial Decree 94/2014, the MiBACT (Ministry of Cultural Heritage and Activities and Tourism) introduced the "Sunday at the museum" (#DomenicalMuseo), an initiative that provides for **free entry to all museums** and areas state archaeological sites of our country on the first Sunday of the month.
  > With Ministerial Decree 13/2019, which came into force on 28 February, the Ministry then limited the validity of this initiative to only the first Sundays of the month which go from October to March.
- **Domenica Metropolitana** initiative

  - while residents

  > [Free Museums Florence 2023 > First Sunday of the month and beyond](https://www.imuseidifirenze.it/musei-gratis-firenze/)
  > The famous "Sunday of the Florentine" - which for some years has become "Metro Sunday" - provided **for all citizens residing in Florence and its province** free admission to the Florentine Civic Museums  on the second Sunday of the month.
  >
  > Since 2015, however, the Municipality of Florence has decided to align the "Sunday of the Florentine" with the "Sunday at the museum": at the moment, therefore, even the Florentine Civic Museums are free **for residents** every first Sunday of the month .

---

**Sources**:

- [2023-08-28: Sunday at the Museum in Florence](https://www.firenzemadeintuscany.com/en/article/sunday-at-the-museum-in-florence-and-tuscany/)

  - [Free Museums Florence 2023 > First Sunday of the month and beyond](https://www.imuseidifirenze.it/musei-gratis-firenze/)

    - translated to english in web browser
    - The next Sunday with free admission is September 3, 2023.